How to auto-import module exports in VSCode/TypeScript, from external packages?
When I type MyCom, it will recognize MyComponent, so when I press tab then enter, it will auto-add the import only if it's a relative path in the project, like at ./components/MyComponent.tsx.
But if MyComponent is at @myorg/example/components/MyComponent, the autocomplete/autoimport doesn't register or work, it never finds it. I'm having to manually write the import instead.
How do I make it so it autoimports? Is this a TypeScript thing, a VSCode thing, or an ESLint thing?
My tsconfig.json is:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2015",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "config.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}


Is most likely related to VSCode.
In tsconfig, you have defined paths mapping for ~/*. This means you can import modules using ~/... instead of relative paths. However for packages like @myorg/example, if you're using these aliases, you may need to ensure that your paths in tsconfig are configured to map those aliases.
For example, if @myorg/example is a local package, you should add a corresponding path mapping:
    "paths": {
  "~/*": ["./*"],
  "@myorg/example/*": ["path/to/your/local/package/*"]
}


That means for the 100's of packages in the node_modules folder, I have to add each one to the tsconfig? That seems like crazy.

Actually paths in tsconfig are used mainly for custom module. auto-imports from packages in node_modules  should be automatically detected. That wy it is likely related to vscode rather than typescript.
I assume you have checked Typescript auto import settings ?

What typescript auto import settings?

ctrl + ,      (go to File ->Preferences -> Settings)
In the search bar type:  typescript auto import
